# How to UV Smart-Unwrap Properly?

Tags: uv

I am lazy. I select my mesh, U -> Smart Unwrap -> Ok. And I would go on and texture it with SubstancePainter or Photoshop. I only create low Poly stuff and this has worked perfectly sofar. Everything is in correct angle and proportion:

[image]

More and more often I get resulst like these, even though I have "Correct Aspect" checked. This makes it impossible to work with:

[image]

Tweaking values doesn't fix anything. The Unwrapped Mesh is in inappropriate proportions and it stays this way. **It's actually FASTER** to redo the entire model and unwrap it again than to complicately mark seams and fiddle with the Mesh in the UV-Editor. Unless of course it comes out bugged again, but sofar that was never the case. The model is pretty much equal, the result is totally out of whack.

**WHY???**

What is happening here behind the curtains that I don't see/understand?

Comment: Chances are your objects have a non uniform scale. Try to apply scale (Ctrl+A->Scale).

Comment: Does disabling "Stretch to UV bounds" make any difference?

Comment: Neither solutions work.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111234/how-to-uv-unwrap-and-scale-uvs-with-python-while-in-object-mode/111307#111307) The python code to the smart unwrap.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a Solution. This is not really an answer as to **why** it is happening but it's too long to put into a comment and at least it fixes the problem.

- Go into Edit Mode
- Press `P` (for Seperate) and select `By Loose Parts`
- Create a Cube somewhere in the scene
- Select all the loose parts of your model and then the cube so the
  cube is the active object and press `Ctrl+J` (for join)
- Go back into Edit mode and delete the Cube, unwrap: done.

This is the same procedure by the way that I frequently use to set the rotation and scale of an object to 1.

Comment: It probably works because in the joining process the meshes take on a uniform scale (the scale of the cube). Have you tried applying scale as @Dimali suggested? It would be easier.

Comment: Yes. That did not work.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the unwrapping algorithm is using the cube mesh like a bounding box to set the scale, or something like that. Can you upload the .blend to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: I will if I encounter the error again. Unfortunately I have no blend file right now with this problem.